# IndexError: string index out of range - How do I get this error when the index does not go outside the range of called list?

Tags: python, list, indexing, methods

Inside a method, I am calling all of the elements inside a nested list. Here is the code where the error message leads me:

```
    def code_from_conditions(self):
        for i in range(0, len(self.list_of_lists[2])):
            if self.list_of_lists[2][i] == "Yes":
                self.list_of_lists[2][i] = "tfa_3895"
            else:
                self.list_of_lists = str(0)
```

Specifically, it is this code right here:

```
if self.list_of_lists[2][i] == "Yes":
```

Now, my first instinct was to change this line:

```
for i in range(0, len(self.list_of_lists[2])):
```

to this:

```
for i in range(0, len(self.list_of_lists[2]) - 1):
```

But after getting the same error message, I've decided to test whether or not I can print all of the elements inside the list I am calling:

```
    def code_from_conditions(self):
        for i in range(0, len(self.list_of_lists[2])):
            print(self.list_of_lists[2][i])
```

and it works! So if I am doing basically the same thing which is calling all elements inside a list but it is inside an if/else statement, then why do I get the error?

Comment: Look very closely at what the `else` branch is doing

Answer (score 0):

In the `else` branch you assign `self.list_of_lists = str(0)`. This means that in the be `self.list_of_lists` is no longer list of lists but `"0"` and therefore this will yield IndexOutOfRange error since `len(self.list_of_lists` is 1.

Comment: Oh, I overlooked that one. Once I've changed it to self.list_of_lists[2][i] then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The string index out of range means that the index you are trying to access does not exist. In a string, that means you're trying to get a character from the string at a given point. If that given point does not exist , then you will be trying to get a character that is not inside of the string.

```
How do I get this error when the index does not go outside the range of called list?
```

makes no sense.